# Import error in django settings . How to remove the error?

Tags: django

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'file-patn/settings' (Is it on sys.path?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

My code has this

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

What changes need to be done in the code to remove the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add this:

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'application_path.settings'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that, you wanted to specify the Python import like:

```
file-patn.settings
```

instead?